# Do not repaint QML object

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, repaint

Is there a way to simply tell the object not to repaint? For example so that a `Rectangle` object will not change color after changing `color` property.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It may be possible by using `QSignalBlocker` to "incapacitate" the object. Will require some C++ code though.

Comment: @Mitch What I am trying to achieve is being able to stop refreshing the application while loading data. Loading big amount of data causes hiccups in rendering UI (imagine having multiple animated objects). I know work arounds - for example using `Item.grabToImage()` could do the work. I was just wondering if there is simple switch to enable/disable UI rendering. Hence this simple question :)

Comment: Ah, I understand. `Item.grabToImage()` is a good idea, and probably as simple as you can get.

Comment: On a side note, it would have been nice if it was possible to mute signals or have properties without notification signals in QML...

Comment: How are you loading big chunks of data exactly?

Comment: @peppe I use `Qt.createComponent()` and load QML file. This file is a whole new application view, also creating new objects from QML files, loading images and so on. Changing every `Component.createObject()` function to `Component.incubateObject()` and setting `asynchronous` flag of every `Image` object to true does not fully prevent UI rendering hiccups.

Comment: Incubation and Loaders are definitely the way to go. At this point however you'd need to run your app into Creator's QML profiler to understand why the hiccups are happening.

Comment: Last time I saw smth like this, it was "cascading" changes to the backend state: each triggering an UI update, and then, more changes, the (quick and dirty) solution was to emit smth like `beginChange()` / `endChange()` signal from the beginning and end of every method that could trigger UI updates, and then simply make the UI only respect the last `endChange` of the nested sequence (with that app, it was possible - as there was a model-like object that would pass all the changes through itself, essentially); in your case, you may need to "squash" updates differently :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple way to do this from QML. I'm not sure that it's even possible to do this in QML; it may be possible in C++.

You can use [Canvas](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html) instead, which gives you control over when rendering happens.